# Tidy replacing &nbsp; with a weird character

Tags: php, tidy

I am using Tidy (with PHP5) with UTF8 input, output, and char encoding enabled.  When I clean a string with an `&nbsp;` in it, it is replacing it with an odd character.  I've tried messing with the tidy config but nothing I try seems to work.

Before Tidy:

```
This is a test. &nbsp;Why does this not work?
```

After Tidy:

```
This is a test. ▒Why does this not work?
```

I don't know what the character is, but I assume it has something to do with the encoding of the enteties in utf8.  Any ideas as to how I can get tidy to just leave the `&nbsp;` alone?

Comment: no-break space is a different character than space in utf8 : http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

I guess you'll have to use `str_replace` before Tidy

Comment: I need the `&nbsp;` in there though because without it, HTML won't render two spaces on the screen.

Comment: What about using `&#x00A0;` instead of `&nbsp;`. Maybe tidy's looking for it explicitly?

Comment: I tried this, and it gives the same result.  I think its trying to encode an actual non-breaking space character instead of leaving the entity alone.  I would like tidy to just treat it like plain text, and ignore any conversion on the entity itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried the [preserve-entities](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#preserve-entities) config option?

Comment: Go figure, the only option I missed.  That works, thank you very much!