# Using Tidy2 for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, tidy

Something realy strange happend when i try use [Tidy2](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/68a9e74)  on my html pages. 
HTML Entities change from this `&nbsp;` to this xA0 ([screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3260616/screen.gif))

I try different settings in config file but nothing help. Please, some advise

Comment: dead dropbox link :/

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the preserve-entities to 1

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#preserve-entities

just add to the end of the config file

```
preserve-entities: 1
```

to open the config file go to:
Plugins > Tidy2 > Edit config *n*

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669947/2455951

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use Tidy2, go to: Plugins->Tidy2->Show Config Help

There you will find how to do a configuration. Each key word has its corresponding reasons.

I just try to change the default config to achieve my purpose. I wanted to avoid thisgs as 
'&#39' when my code was `'&apos;'`. (probably your problem)

At the end the problem was to set.

```
 quote-marks: no
```

The reason I found in the file 'Show Config Help' is:

This option specifies if Tidy should output " characters as " as is preferred by some editing environments. The apostrophe character ' is written out as ' since many web browsers don't yet support '.

1. I'm working with HTML5 and using an encoding in latin1:

2.1 I use  Plugins->Tidy2->Edit config1

2.2 I applied it with  Plugins->Tidy2->tidy (config 2)

Mi config file is this:

```
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 2
wrap: 132
markup: yes
output-html: yes
numeric-entities: yes
quote-marks: no
quote-nbsp: yes
quote-ampersand: no
break-before-br: no
uppercase-tags: no
uppercase-attributes: no
new-inline-tags: cfif, cfelse, math, mroot, 
  mrow, mi, mn, mo, msqrt, mfrac, msubsup, munderover,
  munder, mover, mmultiscripts, msup, msub, mtext,
  mprescripts, mtable, mtr, mtd, mth
new-blocklevel-tags: cfoutput, cfquery
new-empty-tags: cfelse
char-encoding: latin1
output-encoding: no
input-encoding: no
```

Comment: As of 2017-May-04 Help points to a 404 page. The package maintainer needs to update the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I encoutered the same problem.  After search and experiment, I found that UTF-8 encoding and these settings don't change **'&nbsp;** (the definitive setting is numeric-entities: no):

```
indent: auto  
indent-spaces: 2  
wrap: 132  
markup: yes  
output-html: yes  
numeric-entities: no  
quote-marks: no  
quote-nbsp: yes  
quote-ampersand: no   
break-before-br: no  
uppercase-tags: no  
uppercase-attributes: no  
new-inline-tags: cfif, cfelse, math, mroot,  
mrow, mi, mn, mo, msqrt, mfrac, msubsup, munderover,  
munder, mover, mmultiscripts, msup, msub, mtext,  
mprescripts, mtable, mtr, mtd, mth  
new-blocklevel-tags: cfoutput, cfquery  
new-empty-tags: cfelse
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with your encoding settings.

Check if you have `char-encoding: raw` or `output-encoding: raw`. In that case you need to change it to whatever encoding you need (utf8 for example).

Comment: both exist, both set in utf8, not help at all

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix:

Main Menu -> Encoding -> Encode in ANSI

The default config file is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you have encoding utf8 without bom convert it to utf8

my config is:
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 2
quiet: yes
input-encoding: utf8
output-encoding: utf8